# ¿Como puedo colocar - en una url()?

Tags: php, html, url

Tengo un problema y es que quiero en código php colocar una URL pero parte de esta tiene un guion (-) y lo que sigue después lo borra en la url.
¿Como puedo hacer que reconozca estos caracteres?.

```
$option .= '<div class="col-xl-12 main-manu"><a class="" href='.url('shop?category=').$parents->categories_name.'>'. $parents->categories_name .'</a> <a class=""' . $hasChild . '></a> </div>';
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con *lo que sigue*? Debes poner entre los paréntesis todo lo que sea parte de la URL. Por el momento solo estás poniendo esto: `'shop?category='`

Comment: ¿Estas seguro de que el problema no se debe a que no has puesto entre comillas el valor del `href`?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con:

Tengo un problema y es que quiero en código php colocar una URL pero parte de esta tiene un guion (-) y lo que sigue después lo borra en la url. ¿Como puedo hacer que reconozca estos caracteres?.

```
$option .= '<div class="col-xl-12 main-manu"><a class="" href="'.url('shop?category=').$parents->categories_name.'">'. $parents->categories_name .'</a> <a class=""' . $hasChild . '></a> </div>';
```

Nota que en las cadenas fijas que estas usando no tienes "" para rodear el valor que vas a calcular.